# Reset an Onservable to null when using a value binding on a Kendo UI Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, observable

I am initiating a [Kendo UI Dropdown List](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/mvvm) by binding the widget to an Observable object. How do I "reset" the value binding to null once a selection is made if the `valuePrimative` property on my dropdown is set to false?

HTML:

```
    <select 
        data-role="dropdownlist" 
        data-text-field="name" 
        data-value-field="id" 
        data-option-label="Select to add..."
        data-bind="source: rootData, value: selectedValue">
    </select>
    <button class='add-to-list-button k-button k-add' data-bind="click: add enabled: selectedValue">+</button>
```

Observable:

```
    this.widgetObservable = kendo.observable({
        rootData: this.rootData,
        selectedValue: null,
        myList: [],
        delete: (e) => {
            this.deleteItem(e);
        },
        add: (e) => {
            this.addItem(e);
        }
    });
```

Resetting the selected option on the dropdown (`$('select', this.$container).data('kendoDropDownList').select(0)` will indeed reset my dropdown, but it does not clear out my `selectedValue` variable.

If `valuePrimitive` option was set to true, I could reset the `selectedValue` variable to `-1`, which would indeed reset the variable and disable my button, but that means that the value returned by the dropdown would be primitive, forcing me to go look for the original object in some mapping object.

Ideally, when I select a value and click the 'Add' button, I want to essentially, do stuff with the selected OBJECT, then reset the dropdown to its original state.

I've seen it suggested to use a [Combobox instead of a Dropdown](https://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist---how-to-clear-selection) if I want to clear the selection because the dropdown always has a selected value (which makes sense), but that begs the question, whats selected after initial load (before any selection) and why can't I just reset to that initial value? Also, I don't want the extra functionality that comes with the combo box.

Should I not even bother with the `enabled` binding on the button?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
delete: function(e) {
    this.set('selectedValue', null);
}
```

if you use the `(e) => {}` syntax your this won't be the observable so watch out.

your drop down should react to this through mvvm.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't set to null since I am not using primitives; I need the dropdown to return an object, so once I set `selectedValue` to null (a primitive), I get an error. In other words, your solution only works when the valuePrimitive option on the dropdown is true, and this particular solution is documented in many places.